# why "asmlinkage" is needed in linux system calls implementation?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, system-calls, abi

I am learning now about system calls on a linux OS, and I saw that every system call is implemented with the `asmlinkage` directive.
I know it means that every parameter for the function is passed on the stack,
but I didn't understand why do we need this? (why don't we use fast call?).

For example the system call:

```
 asmlinkage long sys_getjiffies( void )
    {
        return (long)get_jiffies_64();
    }
```

is using asmlinkage.
Why is it necessary?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could add what kernel version, source file, and line you found this example at.

Comment: *i know it means that every parameter for the function is passed on the stack* I don't think that's true.  The x86-64 entry point used to pass args normally, following the standard register-arg ABI, before Meltdown/Spectre mitigation changed it to go through a C wrapper instead of just `call *syscall_table(,%rax,8)`  or similar.

Comment: For the x86-32 version it does have an `__attribute__((regparm(0)))`.

Comment: so if i am wrong about the meaning of "asmlinkage", can someone please explain? and i didn't understand yet why it is used in every system call.

Comment: IDK, seems weird to me.  Hand-written asm could just pass args in the regparm registers.  But perhaps it was already written before they decided to compile with `-mregparm=3`, and nobody cared enough about 32-bit kernels to ever bother porting the asm to a better calling convention

Comment: [Originally](https://github.com/kalamangga-net/linux-1.0/blob/733a0282d6e855c5eee87c86733dca8c0f3e1a42/include/linux/linkage.h) `asmlinkage` merely expanded to `extern "C"` to avoid name mangling if you are compiling with a C++ compiler (which nowadays is not supported at all).  When using a C compiler it expanded to nothing.

Comment: I think its purpose is to just be a sort of hook: in case some platform / compiler / etc needs something special to build functions that can be called from assembly with the right conventions, then they can define the `asmlinkage` macro appropriately, and not have to add `#ifdef`s around several hundred function definitions.  For other platforms the defaults may be fine, and they can define `asmlinkage` as nothing.